# Get Array indexing record sum

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I have array in following format. I want sum of 'amount' column from whole array so that it will give me $sum = 150(which is sum of [PaymentLine][0]['Amount'] + [PaymentLine][1]['Amount']). 
My demo code is

```
 [PaymentLine] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 2
                    [AccountID] => 68
                    [Amount] => 100
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [AccountID] => 15
                    [Amount] => 50
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                )

        )
```

Can anyone suggest me proper way to achieve this??

Comment: `array_sum(array_map(function (array $item) { return $item['amount']; }, $array))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$array` contains the above stated array dimensions, this may help you

```
foreach ($array['PaymentLine'] as $k => $v) {
$sum +=$v['Amount']
}
```

If you are using php >=5.5 then there is a cool function called `array_column()`

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($array['PaymentLine'], 'Amount'));
```

Comment: It is possible by any php function, without forloop??

Comment: direct function is possible only from php 5.5, i.e above stated function `array_column()`

Comment: shatheesh  :- I had already edited this question and don't know why people are giving downvote to my question..can u please upvote for question if it seems proper to you?